# Apache .htaccess redirect for webdav storage?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, webdav

I have the webdav service up and running on my Apache web server.  When I upload a file via webdav, it is placed at the root of my public_html directory.  I also have full visibility to all the files and directories under public_html.  Is it possible to redirect webdav to point to a specific file directory, preferably to a directory like https://mysite.com/storage?

I'm assuming this will be a htaccess technique but would appreciate any advice or pointers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this in your htaccess and place the htaccess in doc root

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /storage/ [R,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you.  Your htaccess technique successfully routes all requests to mysite.com to mysite.com/storage.  Is there a way to only redirect those who come to the site from webdav?  In other words, the URL would read http://mysite.com/webdav but the actual storage of the files happens at http://www.mysite.com/storage?  The problem I am having is that all traffic is now being redirected to the /storage folder.